# Formik checkbox not working properly with withFormik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, formik-material-ui

I have such code in my Form component which basically renders list of checkboxes based on array coming from props.

```
{permissions?.map((permissions) => {
                        return (
                            <Styled.FormItem key={permissions.name}>
                                <Field
                                    as={FormControlLabel}
                                    name="permissions"
                                    value={permissions.name}
                                    label={permissions.name}
                                    control={<Checkbox color={'primary'} />}
                                />
                            </Styled.FormItem>
                        );
                    })}
```

As I understand from Formik documentation sample for checkboxes in this way I get `permissions` field in values with array of checked values. And this works fine until I want to make some of the fields be prechecked when I open the form.
I am using `withFormik` HOC in such way

```
const EditRoleFormFormik = withFormik<FormProps, any>({
    mapPropsToValues: ({ role }) => {
        const permissions = role?.permissions.map(({ name }) => {
            return { name };
        });
        return { id: role?.id, name: role?.name, permissions: ['AB_TEST_VIEW'] };
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    handleSubmit: (values: Partial<Role>, { props: { onSubmit } }) => {
        onSubmit(values);
    },
})(Form);
```

My assumption was that by defining permissions field in `mapPropsToValues` I can make some fields prechecked (since above I hardcoded only AB_TEST_VIEW I expected only this to be prechecked). But this doesn't work. How can I precheck checkboxes using this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the selected permissions in a separate property.

```
    const permissions = [
        {
            name: "p1",
        },
        {
            name: "p2",
        },
        {
            name: "p3",
        }
    ]

    const selectedPermissions = ["p1", "p2"]
```

Set formik `initialValues`

```
initialValues = {
    {
        permissions: permissions,
        selectedPermissions: selectedPermissions
    }
```

And use `permissions` to create the checkboxes but name it `selectedPermissions`

```
{permissions?.map((permission) => {
    return (
        <label>
            <Field
                type="checkbox"
                name="selectedPermissions"
                value={permission.name}
            />
            {permission.name}
        </label>


    )
})}
```

Hope that helps.